# Microsoft Outlook API Integration with other JEE environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration, outlook-addin, outlook-api

I'm new to Office 365 Outlook API, I have followed this tutorials from Microsoft to deal with their API.

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/java-tutorial*

But in my case I need the integration in the opposite side, I want to add the code in Outlook side and this code should get some information from my site that was built using JEE .

Can anyone help me with any tutorial or any site link as a starting point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Outlook Web-Addin will be Helpful in this scenario ,which allows integration between your (web Applications developed using JEE or MVC) and Outlook Client running on desktop.

Here is the link to the documentation to create one without Visual Studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial